# sudo apt-get upgrade error

Tags: apt, update

after sudo apt-get upgrade, the screen changed with xbox.

I just did `sudo apt-get update`
and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then screen changed white and I cant see the file image.

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

thank you Dmitry Grigoryev

I tried `sudo apt-get update` then command tells me do `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

after rebooting the original screen come back.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the update went down without errors, I suggest you reboot and see if the missing icons come back.

If there were errors during the update, I suggest you back up important files and try to run the update again, trying to fix whatever errors you can. For instance, if the update command tells you it cannot connect to server, you check the network, reboot the router, etc. If the update command complains that there's no disk space, you free up some, and so on.

Rebooting after a failed upgrade may result in a system which cannot boot.